# VBA: Access to registry while preprocessing

Tags: vba, excel, compilation, preprocessor-directive

I want to conditionally compile code in one VBAproject, with a condition that depends on some registry-entry. Is this somehow possible in VBA?

I know that there are some simple preprocessing possibilites in VBA, but I can not see if it is possible to somehow access the registry while preprocessing. Or Maybe some other possibility to check the registry before compiling.

Since I get a compile error because of some missing reference(and thus missing class object), I aim to check the registry before compiling.

P.s. I only want to read registry-entries.

As an example. How to reach debug.print in the following, i.e. avoiding compile errors.

```
sub sub1()
   dim testobj as new nonexistingobject
   sub2 testobj
   debug.print "Arrived at this point"
end sub

sub sub2( byref testobj as nonexistingobject)
   *do some stuff with testobj*
end sub
```

Comment: Why not check the existence of the object itself?

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: ok, i posted some code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using early binding (`Dim obj as myObject`), use late bindings with `CreateObject`. This way you will be able to handle the case where the object doesn't exists:

```
Sub test()
    Dim obj As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    obj = CreateObject("myObject")
    if Err then Exit Sub 'if the object wasn't found exit the function
    on error goto 0 'set back the error handling to its previous state

    'rest of the code
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. It partially solves the problem. The remaining part where I do not see how( if at all) I could use late binding is the following: Passing those (potentially not existing) classes to subs. Maybe it would work, if I only pass objects, and then specify in the "sub"-function/sub(with late binding).

Comment: @mr.gaussian My opinion is if the object is not present, you shouldn't proceed with the rest of the code, just display an error message.

Comment: yes, that is what I want to do. But, if I have those objects as parameters in definitions of some subs/functions then I can not see how to check the existence. thus I can not display an error, because even before the code executes, there is a compile error. do you think I should then only use the general 'object' type as parameter in functions in the case, that it is not assured that the object exists.   

In Praxis, what I want to do is to give the User an error message, if he has not the necessary software on his system(which I include the dll's of by referencing).

Comment: @mr.gaussian You should check the existence of the object once in your main sub. for sub-functions/subs, use `Object` for parameters, and use `CreateObject` for local variables. That way there shouldn't be any error, since the code should only execute if the object is present

Answer (score 0):

It is not feasible. All the symbols and conditions that are tested by VBA Directives are build from *literals* or *expressions* that include only operators (excepting the `Is` operator, I think).

Function calls are not allowed when declaring directive symbols and conditions, and the only way to access registry in VBA is via API (like `WScript.Shell` for example), which means function call.

Further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx6yas69.aspx

Answer (score 0):

VBA does not directly provide access to the entire Windows Registry, but you can use a workaround.

```
Dim RegObj as Object
Set RegObj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

RegObj.RegDelete RegKeyString
RegObj.RegWrite RegKeyString
Str = RegObj.RegRead RegKeyString

Set RegObj = Nothing
```

If the RegKeyString is not found, it'll throw an error, so you need some `OnError -> Key Doesn't Exist` kind of code.

Not sure of the preprocessing part, but you could run your code in the `Workbook_Open` event handler to make sure this part runs before anything else.