# How to return information from Excel to the caller

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I start Excel from the command line and my add-on does some work. when it's done, I want to return some info to the caller. At least 0/1 for success failure or better also an optional error-message.

By caller I mean the command or process that started Excel. e.g. in a Windows command script I could call excel like this:

```
Excel.exe SomeWorkbook.xlsx /p C:\Somedir /e
```

when you call an executable in Windows, it can return an numeric code or set an error.

in a script you could check the result like this:

```
if %errorlevel% neq 0 (
    echo some error occurred...
)
```

MessageBoxes, etc. are no option, because this whole task should be triggered by another application automatically without any user-interaction.

How can we do that?

Comment: By "caller" do you mean the user at the console or do you mean an app??

Comment: Why does MsgBox not work for you?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But if you want another application to communicate with Excel you can still use a temporary file or the registry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558164/vba-access-to-registry-while-preprocessing

Comment: @CharlesWilliams  Will **MsgBox** display if Excel is run minimized?

Comment: The `application.caller` as in the cell that excel is working from, or the caller as in command prompt? Or as in the user?

Comment: Message-boxes etc. are not an option, because the process must execute automatically without user-interaction.

Comment: Set an Environment Variable in your Excel VBA code before it exits.  Then write a command line procedure that runs the Excel command and after, checks the environment variable and sets that as the procedures exit status.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I've tried that, but could not get it to work: i.e. in `Workbook_Open()` I use the Win-Api: `SetEnvironmentVariableA` to set an env var and then call `Application.Quit` - but in the script , the env-var is not defined. Maybe I am doing something wrong in the script - do you have a working example of this?

Comment: Did you try a global variable?

Comment: I cannot use global variables, because multiple excel processes may be started in parallel - I think I'll have to use temporary files...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using text files: i.e when the add-on finished correctly, it will create an empty file `OK.txt` and when an error occurred it will create a file named `ERR.txt` that contains the error-message.

Now it's easy for the calling script to check the result:

- `OK.txt` exists: everything is fine - delete `OK.txt`
- no file exists: a fatal error has happened: show a general error message
- `ERR.txt` exists: an error occured: maybe display the error text (contents of the text-file) to the user, delete `ERR.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the status bar:
Application.StatusBar = “your message here”
As far as I know, the message box requires a button to be clicked: macro will wait...